# Flutter how to get last PageView scroll direction

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to get which direction(left or right) user swiped by using `PageView`.
I was able to get direction like so.

**Code:**

```
 PageController _controller;

  @override
  void initState() {
    _controller = new PageController()..addListener(_listener);
    super.initState();
  }

  _listener() {
    if (_controller.position.userScrollDirection == ScrollDirection.reverse) {
      print('swiped to right');
    } else {
      print('swiped to left');
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(),
      body: PageView.builder(
          itemCount: 10,
          controller: _controller,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            return new Center(child: Text('item ${++index}'));
          }),
    );
  }
```

However since it's not getting end of scrolling, `print` method
return this many times. 
Is there way I can get this after current page switched to next page completely?

> flutter: swiped to right
>   flutter: swiped to right
>   flutter: swiped to right
>   flutter: swiped to right
>   flutter: swiped to right
>   flutter: swiped to right
>   flutter: swiped to right
>   flutter: swiped to right
>   flutter: swiped to right
>   flutter: swiped to right
>   flutter: swiped to right

Comment: see if this helps https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/PageController/viewportFraction.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Compare the current `_controller.page.round()` with the value from the previous listener invocation (store the previous value in the `State`).

- If the current value is greater than the previous value, the user swiped to the right.
- If the current value is lower than the previous value, the user swiped to the left.

Comment: Working but there is a delay. If the user scrolls fast it never gets updated.

Answer (score 18):

A better solution is as follows, using the PageView widget's built in function.

```
 PageView(
 onPageChanged: (int page) { 
 // this page variable is the new page and will change before the pageController fully reaches the full, rounded int value
   var swipingRight = page > pageController.page;
   print(swipingRight);
  },
```

Answer (score 4):

None of the solutions here worked for me, figuring this out was a huge headache.

I ended up using a gesture detector and disabling the PageView gestures entirely.

The `NeverScrollableScrollPhysics()` is how you disable the PageView's built-in gestures.

```
class MyPageView extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyPageViewState createState() => _MyPageViewState();
}

class _MyPageViewState extends State<MyPageView> {
  PageController _pageController;
  Duration pageTurnDuration = Duration(milliseconds: 500);
  Curve pageTurnCurve = Curves.ease;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    // The PageController allows us to instruct the PageView to change pages.
    _pageController = PageController();
  }

  void _goForward() {
    _pageController.nextPage(duration: pageTurnDuration, curve: pageTurnCurve);
  }

  void _goBack() {
    _pageController.previousPage(
        duration: pageTurnDuration, curve: pageTurnCurve);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: GestureDetector(
        // Using the DragEndDetails allows us to only fire once per swipe.
        onHorizontalDragEnd: (dragEndDetails) {
          if (dragEndDetails.primaryVelocity < 0) {
            // Page forwards
            print('Move page forwards');
            _goForward();
          } else if (dragEndDetails.primaryVelocity > 0) {
            // Page backwards
            print('Move page backwards');
            _goBack();
          }
        },
        child: PageView.builder(
            itemCount: 10,
            controller: _pageController,
            // NeverScrollableScrollPhysics disables PageView built-in gestures.
            physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              return new Center(child: Text('item ${++index}'));
            }),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Your code is okay just add a setState
like this

```
PageController _controller;

  @override
  void initState() {
    _controller = new PageController()..addListener(_listener);
    super.initState();
  }

  _listener() {
    setState(() {
      if (_controller.position.userScrollDirection == ScrollDirection.reverse) {
        print('swiped to right');
      } else {
        print('swiped to left');
      }
    });

  }
```