# How to disable scroll in PageView in a particular direction in flutter

Tags: flutter, scroll, flutter-pageview

I'm new to flutter and am learning about Pageview. In my app I have made an onboarding screen. Is there a way to disable scroll in a particular direction? What I'm trying to achieve is that the user should not be able to scroll/swipe left when they are on the first page and should not be able to scroll/swipe right when they are on the last page. I know you can disable scroll physics by using `NeverScrollableScrollPhysics()`, but is there a way to give it a direction?

Code:

```
PageView(
  onPageChanged: (newValue) {
    //Update the page
  },
  physics: activePage == 0 ||
          activePage == pages.length - 1
      ? const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics()
      : const PageScrollPhysics(),
  controller: pageController,
  children: [
    for (var page in pages) PageWidget(page: page),
  ],
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer. Simply set physics of the PageView to ClampingScrollPhysics().

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this behaviour like this

set physics as `NeverScrollableScrollPhysics()` then

you can have a `next` button, where you can use `pageView.animateToPage()` function to animate to next page

This will give you the feel of swiping and can achieve this behaviour.

Here by using this you can only move forward not backward in your `pageView`

If you have any doubts let me know

Comment: I don't need a button to scroll to the next/prev page. Only user can scroll to change pages. I just don't want the user to scroll on further when all the pages have ended or scroll back when the user in on the first page.

Answer (score 0):

To get that kind of behaviour you can give `controller` to pageview and get swipe direction.

Then you can block the scroll according to you.
Refer the link below

https://stackoverflow.com/a/63188690/15438326

Answer (score 0):

To disable scrolling in a particular direction in a **PageView** widget in Flutter, you can use a combination of **physics** and **onPageChanged** callback to control the scroll behavior. For example.
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

```
class DisableScrollDirectionPageView extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _DisableScrollDirectionPageViewState createState() =>
      _DisableScrollDirectionPageViewState();
}

class _DisableScrollDirectionPageViewState
    extends State<DisableScrollDirectionPageView> {
  PageController _pageController;
  int _currentPage = 0;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _pageController = PageController(initialPage: _currentPage);
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _pageController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  void _handlePageChange(int page) {
    setState(() {
      _currentPage = page;
    });
  }

  bool _isScrollable(int page) {
    // Enable scrolling only for pages other than page 2
    return page != 2;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Disable Scroll Direction'),
      ),
      body: PageView(
        controller: _pageController,
        physics: _isScrollable(_currentPage)
            ? AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics()
            : NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
        onPageChanged: _handlePageChange,
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            color: Colors.blue,
            child: Center(
              child: Text(
                'Page 1',
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 24, color: Colors.white),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Container(
            color: Colors.red,
            child: Center(
              child: Text(
                'Page 2',
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 24, color: Colors.white),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Container(
            color: Colors.green,
            child: Center(
              child: Text(
                'Page 3',
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 24, color: Colors.white),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

In the above code **DisableScrollDirectionPageView** widget creates a **PageView** with three pages. The **_isScrollable** method checks the current page index and returns true if scrolling is enabled for that page, and false otherwise. The physics property of the PageView is set to either AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics() or **NeverScrollableScrollPhysics**() based on the **_isScrollable** value.